# Serverside JS coverage for IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, code-coverage, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to run code coverage without browser in intelliJ?

http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/monitoring-code-coverage-for-javascript.html
This is only coverage tutorial by Jetbrains, but both of these require a browser, so i can't test my Node.js code. I bet i'm not the only one who want's a coverage report of their Node.js code using IntelliJ :)

Karma and JsTestDriver seems both to run tests in browser so no Node.js code can be tested with those. I can anyways run mocha tests straight from idea, but without coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited 2018**

It's been possible already quite a long now. Works out of the box for jest, and apparently very easy for mocha/istanbul too, see:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-unit-tests-on-mocha.html#ws_mocha_code_coverage
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-unit-tests-on-jest.html#ws_jest_code_coverage

Answer (score 3):

There is no such feature in WebStorm. Please vote for [WEB-10373](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10373)